# Как перемещать увеличенную картинку в Android?

Tags: java, android

Пишу небольшое простенькое приложение для школьников, и столкнулся с проблемой - есть текст по биологии, зоологии, анатомии. К текстам часто идут картинки

```
<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/buttonlayout">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/AtlasImg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     />
            </LinearLayout>
            
            <TextView
                android:text="описание"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/c_opis"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Но бывает что картинка слишком большая для вывода на экран и в таком случае она масштабируется и плохо читается.
Для увеличения я сделал вот такой код

```
public class finish extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "Main";
    String[] mTestArray;

    private boolean isImageScaled = false;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.finish);
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        String fValue = mIntent.getStringExtra("fVariableName");
        String aValue = mIntent.getStringExtra("aVariableName");

        final String splVar = fValue;
        final String[] splittedItem = fValue.split(":");

        int arrayName_ID= getResources().getIdentifier(splittedItem[2] , "array",this.getPackageName());
      mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(arrayName_ID);

        final String[] ArrItem = mTestArray[0].split("::");

        ImageView ImgAnatom = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.AtlasImg);

        ImgAnatom.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!isImageScaled) v.animate().scaleX(2f).scaleY(2f).setDuration(500);
            if (isImageScaled) v.animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).setDuration(500);
            isImageScaled = !isImageScaled;
});
```

Картинка увеличивается, но не видно того что за пределами екрана. Как можно подключить передвижение картинки в контейнере ImgView?

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил благодаря подключению библиотеки https://github.com/jsibbold/zoomage